# Virtualbox won't start because of "retpoline"

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox, gcc

After the 'retpoline' fix for spectre was added to the kernel, Virtualbox would not start. You could rebuild the driver, but it wouldn't install because of the "version magic" mismatch. Had to drop back to a previous kernel (112) to run Virtualbox.

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a System76 Kudu.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title. Instead, add your solution as an answer to the question. (Yes, you can answer your own question.) Also, a link to the other thread would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Answer migrated from the question:

> Solved this by installing `gcc-7`:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gcc-7
> ```
>
> Then (probably not correctly) I created symbolic links to the `7` versions of `gcc`, `gcc-ar`, `gcc-nm`, and `gcc-ranlib` in `/usr/bin`.
>
> After verifying that `gcc --version` reported that it's version 7, I ran the following to recompile and install the `vboxdrv` module:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
> ```
>
> And, viola!, it works.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-153.

Used update-alternatives instead of manual symlink changes - seems to be a more correct way for adding/selecting compiler version.
Still need an additional step to build vboxdrv as build failed due to missing `compiler-gcc7.h`.

Workaround: copy `compiler-gcc5.h` to `compiler-gcc7.h` in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-153/include/linux/`
and create appropriate symlink in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-153-generic/include/linux/`.